# Display Parsed URL Value

Tags: javascript, wordpress, variables

I'm stuck after several hours of banging my head up against the screen.  I'm hoping someone with more knowledge can help me out.  My ultimate goal is to take the parsed URL parameters and display them in the body of my Wordpress page. An example URL maybe 'www.urlexample.com/?var1=red&var2=shoes'.

If I inspect my page, I can see in the session storage the key/value pair displaying.  For example I would see key="var1" with a value="red".  So to mean that means the javascript is working.  Now how can I display this in the body of my page?  For example; "You're favorite color is RED" (where red is var1)

```
<!-- URL Parse Code -->
<script>
    var queryForm = function(settings) {
        var reset = settings && settings.reset ? settings.reset : false;
        var self = window.location.toString();
        var querystring = self.split("?");
        if (querystring.length > 1) {
            var pairs = querystring[1].split("&");
            for (i in pairs) {
                var keyval = pairs[i].split("=");
                if (reset || sessionStorage.getItem(keyval[0]) === null) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem(keyval[0], keyval[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        var hiddenFields = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=hidden]");
        for (var i=0; i<hiddenFields.length; i++) {
            var param = sessionStorage.getItem(hiddenFields[i].name);
            if (param) document.getElementById(hiddenFields[i].name).value = param;
        }
    }
    queryForm();
</script>
<!-- URL Parse Code -->
```

Comment: Take a look at [UrlSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) that should help.

Comment: @Bibberty - About the URLSearchParams... can this capture the landing page at all?  The code above got me the parsed URL variables to store is sessionStorage.  I'm looking to also find a way to store the landing page as a variable.  Thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean the path of the URL ?

Comment: Take a look at [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and perhaps use `const url = new URL(window.location);` from there you can get what you need.

Comment: @Bibberty Alright, making progress via the URL link you noted. The answer below used session data. Any idea in this method how to display the variables in an HTML text field? Below is the code I'm using and can correctly console the values.

```const EnteringURL = 'https://example.com/?campaign=vcampaign&src=vsrc'
const urlObject = new URL(EnteringURL);
  const host = urlObject.host
  const href = urlObject.href
console.log(host)
console.log(href)

let url = new URL(EnteringURL); 
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search.slice(1));
  console.log(url.searchParams.get('campaign'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking in the question above Brett.

```js
const EnteringURL = 'https://example.com/?campaign=vcampaign&src=vsrc';
// const urlObject = new URL(EnteringURL);
// const host = urlObject.host;
// const href = urlObject.href console.log(host) console.log(href) let url = new URL(EnteringURL);
// let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search.slice(1));
// console.log(url.searchParams.get('campaign'));

const mapParams = (p) => Array.from(p.keys()).map(k => `<li>${k} - ${p.get(k)}</li>`).join('');

const mapLoad = (url) => {
  const { host, href, search } = new URL(url);
  const params = new URLSearchParams(search.slice(1));
  document.querySelector('.mapped').innerHTML = `
    <div class="url">URL - ${href}</div>
    <div class="host">HOST - ${host}</div>
    <div class="href">SEARCH - ${search}</div>
    <ul class="params">
      ${mapParams(params)}
    </ul>
  `; 
};

const loadIntoHTML = (url) => {
  const { host, href, search } = new URL(url);
  const params = new URLSearchParams(search.slice(1));
  document.querySelector('.href').innerHTML = encodeURI(href);
  document.querySelector('.host').innerHTML = host;
  document.querySelector('.search').innerHTML = search;
  document.querySelector('.params').innerHTML = mapParams(params);
};

const loadIntoHiddenForm = (url) => {
  const { host, href, search } = new URL(url);
  const params = new URLSearchParams(search.slice(1));
  const campaign = params.get('campaign');
  const src = params.get('src');
  document.querySelector('#href').value = encodeURI(href);
  document.querySelector('#host').value = host;
  document.querySelector('#search-params-campaign').value = campaign;
  document.querySelector('#search-params-src').value = src;
};

document.querySelector('.show').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.hidden-fields').classList.toggle('hide');
});

loadIntoHiddenForm(EnteringURL);
loadIntoHTML(EnteringURL);
mapLoad(EnteringURL);
```

```css
.hidden-fields, .mapped, .loaded {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.hidden-fields input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0.25rem;
  min-width: 375px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="show">Hidden Forms Fields (Click to show)</h2>
<div class="hidden-fields hide">
  <input type="text" id="href" />
  <input type="text" id="host" />
  <input type="text" id="search-params-campaign" /> 
  <input type="text" id="search-params-src" /> 
</div>

<h2>Build the HTML</h2>
<div class="mapped">

</div>

<h2>Load into HTML</h2>
<div class="loaded">
  <div class="href"></div>
  <div class="host"></div>
  <div class="search"></div>
  <ul class="params"> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Getting closer and I seriously appreciate your time!  I may not be explaining this well. I'm learning as I go. My goal is to take the data (host, href, params) and input those values into individual hidden fields on my form (the html part). I was able to accomplish via Session Storage (in part), then realized data like domain, landing page, etc. isn't in Session Storage.  Basically things before the '?'. That led me down the URL path mentioned hoping to get a code to cover all my data points I'm trying to pass.

Comment: For the session storage, I was able to put the session key;value into a <input> field using HTML.  Below is the an idea of what I did.  Basically, I'm trying to do the same thing but with params, and not session storage due to the reasons I noted above. Not sure if it's possible.  Hopefully, this helps clarify. 

```<div>  
<script>
document.getElementById("formfieldId1").value = sessionStorage.getItem('campaign');
document.getElementById("formfieldId2").value = sessionStorage.getItem('src');
</script>
</div>```

Comment: Take a look now, you should have everything you need. Please upvote the answer.

Comment: I'm hoping you can help with one more thing? What if I want to display the individual campaign value ("vcampaign") and src value ('vsrc') in their own fields and not as one long value.  ```const campaign = new URLSearchParams(search.slice(1)).get('campagin')
       document.querySelector('#campaign').value = campaign;
       document.querySelector('#src').value = src;
       document.querySelector('#href').value = encodeURI(href);
       document.querySelector('#host').value = host;
       document.querySelector('#search-params-campaign').value = search;
};```

Comment: ```<h2 class="show">Hidden Forms Fields (Click to show)</h2>
<div class="hidden-fields hide">
  <input type="text" id="campaign" />
  <input type="text" id="src" />
  <input type="text" id="href" />
  <input type="text" id="host" />
  <input type="text" id="search-params-campaign" /> 
</div>```

Comment: Corrected to work as required. Please vote for answer.

Comment: Thanks you very much!  It's showing the values individually now.

Answer (score 1):

If the variables and values are in the session storage:

```
var el = document.getElementById('elementid'); /// get the element on body by its id. 
el.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('key'); /// get the value by key and set the text in the element
```

https://codepen.io/fernandosiebra/pen/NWPPjoO

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm still not able to display.  So on my header.php I added 

<script>
var el = document.getElementById('sand'); /// get the element on body by its id. 
el.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('var1'); /// get the value by key and set the text in the element
</script>

Then on my page I added <div id="sand"></div>. When I search my session storage I see var1 = red (key,value).  Still new at this so I'm still learning! What am I missing?

Comment: create the elements on page with the same id of key on session storage and
put this at end of queryForm  function:
for( var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++ )
{
 var el = document.getElementById(sessionStorage.key(0));
 if( el != null )
    { 
  el.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem(sessionStorage.key(0))
    }
}

Comment: I was able to finally get my head around this to make it work! Thanks so much.